# dnsmasq for local resolution works after running dhclient, then stops working after a few minutes

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dhcp, dnsmasq

I'm running into a strange issue. For the record, I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

I'm trying to configure a custom TLD, call it .mytld, to resolve to 127.0.0.1 so I can host local websites without needing to update `/etc/hosts`.

On this machine, network interfaces are managed by NetworkManager, which *does not* have a line `dns=dnsmasq` in the `[main]` section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

I installed dnsmasq and confirmed it is running.

I edited `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and added:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

I created `/etc/dnsmasq.d/mytld.conf` and added:

```
address=/.mytld/127.0.0.1
```

And I edited `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and added:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

After restarting `NetworkManager` and `dnsmasq` and manually executing `dhclient`, I confirmed that `127.0.0.1` was prepended as a DNS server (10.0.0.1 is my gateway machine):

```
$ nmcli
[ ... ]
DNS configuration:
        servers: 127.0.0.1 10.0.0.1
[snip]
```

Because NetworkManager is managing the network, `/etc/resolv.conf` contains the NM stub server:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 127.0.0.53

$ systemd-resolve --status
[...]
Link 2 (eno1)
         [...]
         DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1
                      10.0.0.1
[snip]
```

After all that, when I ping an arbitrary host.mytld, I get a good response:

```
$ ping -c 1 test.mytld
PING test.mytld (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes of data from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
[ snip ]

$ dig A test.mytld
[ ... ]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
test.mytld.     0   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
[snip]
```

So, it works -- for a little while.

After a few minutes of normal operation, things start to go south. 
 `systemd-resolved` gets pegged at 100% CPU, and `dnsmasq` hovers at about 50% CPU. (I have a 6-core, 12-thread CPU.)

Sample from `top`:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
20659 systemd+  20   0   66368   6448   5272 R  98.7  0.0  27:31.57 systemd-resolve
13834 dnsmasq   20   0   64516   2840   2424 R  59.3  0.0  35:50.65 dnsmasq
```

While this is going on, `*.mytld` still resolves to 127.0.0.1. Then, after a while (can take dozens of minutes), whatever is happening with `systemd-resolved` and `dnsmasq` resolves itself -- both processes are still running, with the same PIDs.

But the response given by NetworkManager no longer works:

```
$ ping -c 1 test.mytld
PING test.mytld (198.105.244.228) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- test.mytld ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

$ dig A test.mytld
;; ANSWER SECTION:
test.mytld.     10  IN  A   198.105.244.228
test.mytld.     10  IN  A   198.105.244.228

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
```

Yet, weirdly, both `nmcli` and `systemd-resolve --status` still report the nameservers as `127.0.0.1` and `10.0.0.1`, in that order.

At this point, I have to re-run `dhclient` to get things working again:

```
$ sudo dhclient
RTNETLINK answers: File exists

$ ping -c 1 test.mytld
PING test.mytld (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.129 ms

--- test.mytld ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.129/0.129/0.129/0.000 ms
```

And then the cycle repeats: after a while, `systemd-resolved` and `dnsmasq` start wigging out; then they recover, but the resolution fails.